# Getting two images that are side by side to decrease and increase as page resizes

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have two div’s that are sitting side by side and contain images in them. When the webpage is the size of my Macbook 13 inch screen the photos sit side by side perfectly. However when I start to increase the screen width the photos start to spread apart leaving a huge gap in between.

How do I get both photos to stay side by side even when the browser page increases or decreases? `

```css
.pic {
  max-width: 100%;
}

#pic2 {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.photosection {
  background-color: black;
  max-width:1400;
  height:363px;
}

#photosection1 {
  float:left;
  max-width: 110vw;
}

#photosection2 {
  max-width:50%;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="photosection">
  <div id="photosection1">
    <a  href="#" class="">
      <span class="text">
        Treat Yourself
        Intuitive Language Coaching
        (Intuitive Life-Coaching + Communication Training)
      </span>
      <img class="pic" src="images/oneonone.jpg" alt="inspiremug">
    </a> 
  </div>

  <div id="photosection2">
    <a  href="" class="">
      <span class="text">
        Treat Your Group, Business or Organization
        I'll bring the sweets!
      </span>
      <img id="pic2" src="images/groupsession.jpg" alt="necklace">
    </a> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#photosection1 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left
}

#photosection2 {
    width: 50%;
    float: right
}
```

add width="100%" to your image tag

```
<img class="pic" src="images/oneonone.jpg" alt="inspiremug" width="100%">
<img id="pic2" src="images/groupsession.jpg" alt="necklace" width="100%">
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for this..?

```css
.pic {
 max-width: 100%;
   }

   #pic2 {
max-width: 100%;
 }

  .photosection {
    background-color: black;
    max-width:1400;
    height:363px;
       }

#photosection1 {
 float:left;
 max-width: 50%;
    }

    #photosection2 {
     max-width:50%;
     float:right;
      }
```

```html
<div class="photosection">


            <div id="photosection1">
             <a  href="#"  class="" >
            <span class="text">
              Treat Yourself
            Intuitive Language Coaching
            (Intuitive Life-Coaching + Communication Training)
              </span>

            <img class="pic" src="http://ias.kgisl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/APJ-Abdul-Kalam.jpg"  alt="inspiremug">
            </a> 

        </div>

        <div id="photosection2">
            <a  href=""  class="" >
            <span class="text">
              Treat Your Group, Business or Organization
              I'll bring the sweets!
              </span>


            <img id="pic2" src="http://ias.kgisl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/APJ-Abdul-Kalam.jpg"  alt="necklace">
            </a> 
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: This worked for me as well but I have a space in between the photos when I increase the browser page.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the display: inline-block property for the divs and size the images to width: 100%.

```
.pic {
 width: 100%;
   }

   #pic2 {
width: 100%;
 }

  .photosection {
    background-color: black;
    max-width:1400;
    height:363px;
       }

#photosection1 {
  display: inline-block;
 float:left;
 max-width: 50%;
    }

    #photosection2 {
      display: inline-block;
     max-width:50%;
     float:right;
      }
```

Does this help?

Comment: The inline-block in not necessary, I guess

Comment: It worked thanks and I didn't need the inline block. But now I have a gap in between the two photos and I tried some margin, should I try some positioning to get remove the space in between?

Comment: I did not get a gap on any zoom level.... did you put the max-width of both divs to be 50%?